# How to wait for state while setting consecutive states in react using UseState Hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, video, next.js, video-streaming

I am calling a function to handle the video play on click and there I want to set consecutive states using useState hook. But I want to wait for first one before cursor goes to next setState(useState Hook) without using useEffect hook to monitor it. This is a function just as an example.

```
const videoPlayHandler = () => {

     setIsPaused(true); //wait for this one 
     setIsPlay(false);  //run just after first state is done
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In react 18, you can force it to do a synchronous rerender by using `flushSync`:

```
import { flushSync } from 'react-dom';

const videoPlayHandler = () => {
  flushSync(() => {
    setIsPaused(true);
  });  
  setIsPlay(false);
}
```

I recommend reading the [notes section on react's flushSync documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#flushsync)

> Note:
>
> flushSync can significantly hurt performance. Use sparingly.
>
> flushSync may force pending Suspense boundaries to show their fallback state.
>
> flushSync may also run pending effects and synchronously apply any updates they contain before returning.
>
> flushSync may also flush updates outside the callback when necessary to flush the updates inside the callback. For example, if there are pending updates from a click, React may flush those before flushing the updates inside the callback.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your question, but in your case it would make more sense to just keep 1 state variable that determines if the video is playing or not.

```
const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);

const videoPlayHandler = () => {
  setIsPlaying(true);
}

const videoPauseHandler = () => {
  setIsPlaying(false);
}
```

Comment: It can be more than two consecutive setStates. So we have to find a solution that solves all scenarios.